# How to determine time-out on Simulink signal

Tags: matlab, simulink

When using a enabled subsystem to simulate the interval of signals which is normal on a vehicle CAN-bus it is not possible for me to determine a time-out on this signal.

Because if the value of a signal is not changing in Simulink you can not compare the old value of the signal to the new value because it will be identical and you don't know if this is because of a time-out or because the signal is just steady.

Is there a way to check this update rate of a signal in Simulink so I can detect a time-out?

Comment: Isn't this more a question of the protocol you are trying to model? I've not developed CAN bus before, but presumably there is a standard data frame with start and end data? Aren't you defining a timeout if the data frame does not complete?

Comment: No I don't think so. CAN messages can be sent cyclically and part of the message is the identifier and the data. If for more than x seconds a certain message is not received a time-out is active. To model the discrete steps of sending the data a trigged subsystem can be used. But if this triggered subsystem is not triggered anymore the data on the signal will remain as is or reset if defined so. But for the receiver of the signals it is not possible to see if the data on the signal in not updated anymore. So my question is: is this true or is there another way to check this?